# require_once() takes two minutes?

Tags: php, require

I have a PHP script which the execution time used to be a few milliseconds.

But yesterday I got complaints that it loads forever. I checked into it and nailed down the problem to a line that uses `require_once();` -- execution time is about two minutes just for that line!

The file to be included contains a bunch of functions and in itself doesn't do anything at that point. It also is just about 35kb in size.

I went through the script logging the `microtime()` and this is the output:

```
0.10887400 1442934181 // start of script
0.13321200 1442934181 // line before "require_once()"
0.16033800 1442934307 // log time again in first line
                      // of the included functions file
0.16048000 1442934307 // back to original script,
                      // line after require_once()
0.16054300 1442934307 // end of script
```

Just for curiosity I've tried to replace `require_once()` with `require()` -- to change.

I don't know what the cause could be and where I should start to debug. It has worked before without problem, and I haven't done any change.

Comment: Most likely something in the required file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require_once` and `require` need to access to the file, read it, and execute it. So you may have multiple problems, but you'll have to check :

- Maybe your hard disk is going bad ?
- Maybe the file is locked by some others process ?
- The file contains now a big function doing too much things

Comment: Thanks, based on your bullets I could find the bug. Don't want to go into the details, but in short the required file was trying to connect to another location which did not exist anymore and timed out.